# Optimizing monte carlo code in python

Tags: options, option-pricing, monte-carlo

What are they key points to use while coding a monte carlo simulation in python?

I have the following monte carlo code :

```
payoff = 0    
for i in range(0,n_sim):
    s = x_o.copy()
    for j in range(0,n_steps):
        for l in range(0,9):
           z = z_net[i][j]
           s[l] = s[l]*math.exp(sig[l]*math.sqrt(delT)*z[l] - (sig[l]**2)*delT/2) 
    s_net= np.prod(s)
    payoff = payoff + max(s_net-k,0)

value = payoff/n_sim
```

Here I have 9 currency crosses each with a correlation structure, so the innermost loop handles that, then I am running n steps each with delT time interval, that is the second loop and the outermost loop is for simulations.

Here x_o are the initial values of currency pairs and z_net is n_sim X n_step X 9 matrix with multivariate normal random numbers

As you can see the time complexity of this code is very high due to three loops. What are the best practices to optimize this. I need to because I have to calculate implied correlation which depends on pricing the option multiple times

Apart from this, can someone provide me a coded blog/article with importance sampling in monte carlo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code performance and not about quantitative finance.

Comment: Hello Zuck and welcome to SE. Your question is about code performance and not about Quantitative finance. You should look for answers on https://stackoverflow.com/.
This being said, one possible way is to use numpy and try to vectorize computations when possible. You will find plenty of articles and blogs about this. See for example: https://hackernoon.com/speeding-up-your-code-2-vectorizing-the-loops-with-numpy-e380e939bed3

Comment: Sure. But can you answer the second part of the question? About importance sampling